# Web2py: insert server concept of datetime

Tags: datetime, web2py

How do I get web2py to insert the current time as understood by the DB server into a datetime field. If I simple use datetime.now() it will insert the client time. In mySQL I would use "NOW()" to get the server time: is there a DAL shortcut for this?

It's for using inside an update_or_insert() statement, if that makes any difference.

Comment: Why does it matter? Is your mySQL server in a different timezone from the server running web2py? Can't you just make an adjustment or use UTC time?

Comment: I can't necessarily guarantee that it is the same (or that the computers are time synced), although I guess it probably is. I'm also accessing / writing this data from outside web2py, potentially from a different machine, so it seems safest in this case to rely on the DB server time, rather than the computer on which web2py is running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can directly pass a SQL function to the DAL `.insert` or `.update_or_insert` methods, as whatever values are passed will end up being quoted. Instead, you will have to use the `.executesql()` method and pass it the SQL to be executed. If you want help generating the SQL, you can use the `._insert` method to generate a string, and then remove the quotes around the "NOW()" function:

```
query = db.mytable._insert(mytime='NOW()').replace("'NOW()'", "NOW()")
db.executesql(query)
```

Of course, you won't be able to use the `.update_or_insert` method with this approach, but its logic is not complicated, so you could easily implement your own helper to handle the `.update_or_insert` logic as well as the above logic.